# PHP Curl - How to pass the wordpress login information via a private Chrome session?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, curl, proxy

The final goal here is to serve some **Wordpress features** from the **admin dashboard** as a **white labeled service** to an **external platform** without Wordpress installed.

In other words, I need to serve the plugin panel exactly as it is to the client without using an iframe in order to keep the same domain name everywhere.

In order to do so I am planning to use a proxy with a little tweak at the beginning of `wp-config.php`.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER'])&&$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER']!=''){
    
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER']);
    
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER']);
}
elseif(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])&&$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']!=''){
    
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']);
    
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']);
}
else{
        
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

    define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}
```

On the frontend side I tried using the Apache proxy with the following `.htaccess` configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule . http://backend.localhost.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

</IfModule>
```

The good news is that everything works fine! I can log in to the WP dashboard without moving out from frontend.localhost.com

Now I would like to provide an alternative way to connect without the apache proxy enabled using a PHP Curl request.

The new `.htaccess` is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^proxy\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /proxy.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Inside `proxy.php` you find a script inspired by https://github.com/rafasashi/php-apache-rewrite-proxy/blob/master/proxy.php

```
<?php
    
    /* Config */
    $upstream_base_url = 'http://backend.localhost.com';
    $timeout = 30; // seconds
    $latency = 0; // simulate latency; seconds

    /* Read incoming request */
    $request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    
    $request_headers = getallheaders();
    $request_headers['Host']=parse_url($upstream_base_url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $request_headers['X-forwarded-Host']=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $request_headers['X-forwarded-Server']=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $request_headers['X-forwarded-For']=$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    
    $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    
    //var_dump($request_body);exit;

    /* Simulate latency */
    if(is_numeric($latency) && $latency > 0){
        
        sleep($latency);
    }

    /* Forward request */
    $url = $upstream_base_url . $request_uri;
    
    $headers = [];
    
    foreach ($request_headers as $key => $value) {
        
        $headers[] = $key . ': ' . $value;
    }

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request_method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false );
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if($response === false) {
        
        header('HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway');
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        
        echo 'Upstream host did not respond.';
        
    } 
    else {
        
        $header_length = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $response_headers = explode("\n", substr($response, 0, $header_length));
        $response_body = substr($response, $header_length);
        
        foreach ($response_headers as $i => $header) {

            if($header = trim($header)){
                
                header($header);
            }
        }       
        
        $mimet = array( 
        'ai' =>'application/postscript',
        'aif' =>'audio/x-aiff',
        'aifc' =>'audio/x-aiff',
        'aiff' =>'audio/x-aiff',
        'asc' =>'text/plain',
        'atom' =>'application/atom+xml',
        'avi' =>'video/x-msvideo',
        'bcpio' =>'application/x-bcpio',
        'bmp' =>'image/bmp',
        'cdf' =>'application/x-netcdf',
        'cgm' =>'image/cgm',
        'cpio' =>'application/x-cpio',
        'cpt' =>'application/mac-compactpro',
        'crl' =>'application/x-pkcs7-crl',
        'crt' =>'application/x-x509-ca-cert',
        'csh' =>'application/x-csh',
        'css' =>'text/css',
        'dcr' =>'application/x-director',
        'dir' =>'application/x-director',
        'djv' =>'image/vnd.djvu',
        'djvu' =>'image/vnd.djvu',
        'doc' =>'application/msword',
        'dtd' =>'application/xml-dtd',
        'dvi' =>'application/x-dvi',
        'dxr' =>'application/x-director',
        'eps' =>'application/postscript',
        'etx' =>'text/x-setext',
        'ez' =>'application/andrew-inset',
        'gif' =>'image/gif',
        'gram' =>'application/srgs',
        'grxml' =>'application/srgs+xml',
        'gtar' =>'application/x-gtar',
        'hdf' =>'application/x-hdf',
        'hqx' =>'application/mac-binhex40',
        'html' =>'text/html',
        'html' =>'text/html',
        'ice' =>'x-conference/x-cooltalk',
        'ico' =>'image/x-icon',
        'ics' =>'text/calendar',
        'ief' =>'image/ief',
        'ifb' =>'text/calendar',
        'iges' =>'model/iges',
        'igs' =>'model/iges',
        'jpe' =>'image/jpeg',
        'jpeg' =>'image/jpeg',
        'jpg' =>'image/jpeg',
        'js' =>'application/x-javascript',
        'kar' =>'audio/midi',
        'latex' =>'application/x-latex',
        'm3u' =>'audio/x-mpegurl',
        'man' =>'application/x-troff-man',
        'mathml' =>'application/mathml+xml',
        'me' =>'application/x-troff-me',
        'mesh' =>'model/mesh',
        'mid' =>'audio/midi',
        'midi' =>'audio/midi',
        'mif' =>'application/vnd.mif',
        'mov' =>'video/quicktime',
        'movie' =>'video/x-sgi-movie',
        'mp2' =>'audio/mpeg',
        'mp3' =>'audio/mpeg',
        'mpe' =>'video/mpeg',
        'mpeg' =>'video/mpeg',
        'mpg' =>'video/mpeg',
        'mpga' =>'audio/mpeg',
        'ms' =>'application/x-troff-ms',
        'msh' =>'model/mesh',
        'mxu m4u' =>'video/vnd.mpegurl',
        'nc' =>'application/x-netcdf',
        'oda' =>'application/oda',
        'ogg' =>'application/ogg',
        'pbm' =>'image/x-portable-bitmap',
        'pdb' =>'chemical/x-pdb',
        'pdf' =>'application/pdf',
        'pgm' =>'image/x-portable-graymap',
        'pgn' =>'application/x-chess-pgn',
        //'php' =>'application/x-httpd-php',
        //'php4' =>'application/x-httpd-php',
        //'php3' =>'application/x-httpd-php',
        //'phtml' =>'application/x-httpd-php',
        //'phps' =>'application/x-httpd-php-source',
        'png' =>'image/png',
        'pnm' =>'image/x-portable-anymap',
        'ppm' =>'image/x-portable-pixmap',
        'ppt' =>'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'ps' =>'application/postscript',
        'qt' =>'video/quicktime',
        'ra' =>'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
        'ram' =>'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
        'ras' =>'image/x-cmu-raster',
        'rdf' =>'application/rdf+xml',
        'rgb' =>'image/x-rgb',
        'rm' =>'application/vnd.rn-realmedia',
        'roff' =>'application/x-troff',
        'rtf' =>'text/rtf',
        'rtx' =>'text/richtext',
        'sgm' =>'text/sgml',
        'sgml' =>'text/sgml',
        'sh' =>'application/x-sh',
        'shar' =>'application/x-shar',
        'shtml' =>'text/html',
        'silo' =>'model/mesh',
        'sit' =>'application/x-stuffit',
        'skd' =>'application/x-koan',
        'skm' =>'application/x-koan',
        'skp' =>'application/x-koan',
        'skt' =>'application/x-koan',
        'smi' =>'application/smil',
        'smil' =>'application/smil',
        'snd' =>'audio/basic',
        'spl' =>'application/x-futuresplash',
        'src' =>'application/x-wais-source',
        'sv4cpio' =>'application/x-sv4cpio',
        'sv4crc' =>'application/x-sv4crc',
        'svg' =>'image/svg+xml',
        'swf' =>'application/x-shockwave-flash',
        't' =>'application/x-troff',
        'tar' =>'application/x-tar',
        'tcl' =>'application/x-tcl',
        'tex' =>'application/x-tex',
        'texi' =>'application/x-texinfo',
        'texinfo' =>'application/x-texinfo',
        'tgz' =>'application/x-tar',
        'tif' =>'image/tiff',
        'tiff' =>'image/tiff',
        'tr' =>'application/x-troff',
        'tsv' =>'text/tab-separated-values',
        'txt' =>'text/plain',
        'ustar' =>'application/x-ustar',
        'vcd' =>'application/x-cdlink',
        'vrml' =>'model/vrml',
        'vxml' =>'application/voicexml+xml',
        'wav' =>'audio/x-wav',
        'wbmp' =>'image/vnd.wap.wbmp',
        'wbxml' =>'application/vnd.wap.wbxml',
        'wml' =>'text/vnd.wap.wml',
        'wmlc' =>'application/vnd.wap.wmlc',
        'wmlc' =>'application/vnd.wap.wmlc',
        'wmls' =>'text/vnd.wap.wmlscript',
        'wmlsc' =>'application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc',
        'wmlsc' =>'application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc',
        'wrl' =>'model/vrml',
        'xbm' =>'image/x-xbitmap',
        'xht' =>'application/xhtml+xml',
        'xhtml' =>'application/xhtml+xml',
        'xls' =>'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'xml xsl' =>'application/xml',
        'xpm' =>'image/x-xpixmap',
        'xslt' =>'application/xslt+xml',
        'xul' =>'application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml',
        'xwd' =>'image/x-xwindowdump',
        'xyz' =>'chemical/x-xyz',
        'zip' =>'application/zip'
        );
     
        $mime_type = '';
        
        $path=parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH);
        
        if($path!=''){
            
            $ext=pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            if(isset($mimet[$ext])){
                
                $mime_type = $mimet[$ext];
            }       
        }
        
        if($mime_type !=''){
            
            header('Content-type: '.$mime_type);
        }
        
        header_remove("Transfer-Encoding");
        
        echo $response_body;
    }

    curl_close($ch);
        
    flush();
    exit;
    die;
```

This works from a public chrome browser session but it doesn't work from a private one. The headers look the same in public and private session except for the time and the hashes inside the cookie string.

How to pass the wordpress login information through a proxy via a private session in Chrome browser?

How to make sure Apache proxy and Curl Proxy behave the same way?

Comment: Doesn't WordPress offer an API for this sort of thing?

Comment: @halfer Using the API for data management is also part of the plan. But in this case I d'like to display the entier admin plugin panel including CSS, javascript and Ajax calls. How can I use the REST API to grant access and get the entier content of the page?